# Go chained function calls?

Tags: function, go

Not sure what the correct name is, but I'm looking for more information about "chained function calls" in Go. For example:

`foo.DoSomething().WithThisOptionalThing()`

So I can use `foo.DoSomething()` but with the possibility to add `.WithThisOptionalThing()` which does something extra's. Is this possible? Please point me in the right direction / provide some examples.

Comment: It's possible if `DoSomething()` returns an object with a `WithThisOptionalThing()` method on it--same as in any other language. I don't really understand what you're asking, though.

Comment: reminds me of builder pattern :)

Answer (score 9):

Basically, you make all your configuration functions keep returning the main "object" while you chain things together and have a final "Go" function or whatever you want to call it to make it perform the action.

Here's an example on [play](https://play.golang.org/p/_OvHGknvBa)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    DoSomething().Go()
    DoSomething().WithThisOptionalThing().Go()
}

type Chainable struct {
    thing bool
}

func DoSomething() *Chainable {
    return &Chainable{}
}
func (c *Chainable) WithThisOptionalThing() *Chainable {
    c.thing = true
    return c
}

func (c *Chainable) Go() error {
    // Actually do something now that it's been configured
    fmt.Println("Thing is", c.thing)
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to know: When it comes to chaining things your methods should either always

- receive `pointers` and return `pointers`

or

- receive `values` and return `values`

or

- receive `values` and return `pointers`

at least they're the working combinations known to me. I couldn't find any documentation on this. If you know what's going on please let me know.